# How can I access a variable in a javascript function from the rest of the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function is the call that is made by the `onchange` event in an html `select` type input.
I assign a variable that value, but it doesn't seem to get accessed by a variable of the same name outside that function, say, in `$(document).ready()`

```
<select form="submitForm" name="frequency" class="meal-type-select" onchange="getFreqVal(this)">
        <option value="O">One Time</option>
        <option value="D">Daily</option>
        <option value="W">Weekly</option>
        <option value="M">Monthly</option>
        <option value="Y">Yearly</option>
        <option value="R">Requested</option>
</select>
```

And the script is this: (There is a lot more to the script, but I've only shown the part relevant to the question, to make it less clattered)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var freqVal;


    $('#addPictures').click(function() {

        alert(freqVal);

    });

});

function getFreqVal(sel)
{
    freqVal =   sel.value;
    alert(freqVal);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Move the `var freqVal;` out of the document ready function.. to start of the script block..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare `freqVal` outside `$(document).ready()`. They're two different functions, essentially.

Comment: Just fyi, by two different functions, I mean `$(document).ready()` and `getFreqVal`

Comment: Yes i understood that.

Answer (score 2):

the variable freqval is outside the scope of getFeqVal(). This is what you should do:

```
<script>
    var freqVal;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#addPictures').click(function() {

            alert(freqVal);

        });

    });

    function getFreqVal(sel)
    {
        freqVal =   sel.value;
        alert(freqVal);
    }
</script>
```

This makes the scope of freqVal global.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your variable inside the function, so it won't be visible outside the function scope. The way you do it, both the functions have their own variable named `freqVal`.

You can use a global variable (member of `window`):

```
<script>

var freqVal; // here

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addPictures').click(function() {
        alert(freqVal);
    });
});

function getFreqVal(sel)
{
    freqVal = sel.value;
    alert(freqVal);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline javascript and use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.meal-type-select').on('change', function() {

        // stuff on select change

    });

    $('#addPictures').on('click', function() {

        var freqVal = $('.meal-type-select').val();

    });
});
```